# Как возмжоно использовать LIMIT при запросе в spring?

Tags: java, sql, spring

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при работе через spring в запросе применить LIMIT? Перелопатила массу вариантов. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
    @Query("select noteId from usersNotes where note = :note limit 1")
    Long findnoteIdbyText_test(@Param("note") String note);
```

Такой вариант тоже пробовала

```
   @Query(value ="select noteId from usersNotes where note = :note limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Notes> findnoteIdbyText_test(@Param("note") String note);
```

Результат: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: Установить атрибут `nativeQuery = true`, тогда языком запроса вместо JPQL будет обычный SQL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47616648/5479247

Comment: Читала. Дополнила ответ, почему-то не работает для меня

Comment: Метод возвращает `List<Notes>`, а в запросе только одно поле `noteId`

Comment: Какую БД используете? В SQL нет такой фразы `limit`, в hql тоже нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть желание использовать `LIMIT 1`, следует установить атрибут `nativeQuery = true`:

```java
@Query("select noteId from usersNotes where note = :note limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
Long findNoteIdByText_test(@Param("note") String note);
```

Или же можно переписать запрос, заменив `limit 1` на `Top / First` в названии метода (текст запроса будет сгенерирован автоматически)

```java
public interface UserNotesRepository extends JpaRepository<UserNotes, Long>
    Optional<UserNotes> findFirstByNote(String note);
}
```

Comment: Подсвечивает ошибку ", nativeQuery = true" - перед запятой, требует добавить параметр "value =", но с ним те же грабли...

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет кому-то еще:

Запрос:

```
@Query("select noteId from usersNotes where note = :note")
List<Long> findnoteIdbyText_test(@Param("note") String note);
```

Вызов:

```
List<Long> calText = notesRepository.findnoteIdbyText_test(update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getText());
Long LastNoteId = calText.isEmpty() ? null : calText.get(calText.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Ваш код делает не то что делал бы LIMIT! надо брать первый элемент а не последний `calText.get(0)` к тому же если будет много записей удовлетворяющих критерию поиска, запрос будет тормозить.